# Crystal reports database connection issues

Tags: crystal-reports

Failed to load database information. Details: The database DLL `crdb_ado.dll` could not be loaded. Error in File (filename) Failed to load database information.

I am receiving this error when i try to run a crystal report from my page. on the server I have installed the CRRedist2008_x86 and the dll file is in the business objects folder, but for some reason it is still not loading. I also checked to make sure I have the `msvcp60.dll` which is also needed but still am unable to run the report.

The server is running Windows Server 2008, has Visual Studio 2005 installed on it (not sure if that makes any difference).  The application ran fine on my local machine, but after uploading it to the server, it's not wanting to play nice.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and open the `crdb_ado.dll` to confirm all the required files are there. Although checking for `msvcp60.dll` is generally the right idea, I've found that people are often looking for the wrong version of those files OR that other required DLLs are also missing.

Also, be sure the redist you are using matches the version of Crystal Reports you have referenced in your project. There is a difference between using, say Crystal Reports 2008 on top of Visual Studio 2005,, versus using the BUNDLED Crystal Reports that comes with Visual Studio 2005 (Or 2008, or 2010 for that matter.).

In fact, sometimes people don't realize that their .NET projects are referencing the "comes with Visual Studio" edition of Crystal Reports because they happen to have Crystal Reports version `<whatever>` installed on their PC.

That said, if you are pretty confident your redist of CRRedist2008_x86 matches what you are using, I'd focus on Dependency Walker to see if it is indicating a missing required file for the `crdb_ado.dll`.